# need help understanding data section of wav file

Tags: audio, wav, audio-recording

I was reading [THIS TUTORIAL](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) on wav files and I have some confusions.
Suppose I use PCM_16_BIT as my encoding format. So this should mean each of my sound samples need 16 bits to represent them shouldn't it?
But in this tutorial, the second figure shows 4 bytes as one sample. Why is that? I suppose because it is trying to show the format for a stereo recorded wav file, but what if I have a mono recorded wav file? Are the left and right channel values equal in this case, or one of the channel values is 0? How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for 16bit stereo you need 4 bytes. For mono, you just need two bytes for 16bit PCM. Check this out:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET

Also read here:

http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=PCM

Comment: so in the second figure in that tutorial that I linked, the right channel won't exist? And every contiguous short value is for one channel's sample only?

Comment: Exactly. So, if L is a short for left channel and R is a short for right channel then we have:

Stereo: L R L R L R (total 6 shorts; 12 bytes; 3 samples)
Mono: L L L L L L (L just means one Short - total 6 shorts; 12 bytes; 6 samples)